# Android System Webview slowness - Ionic App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview, android-webview

We are developing a mobile application using Ionic Platform that uses internally the Android System Webview to render the application, and we are facing random slowness on different Android devices, As per below grid, the application start-up can vary from 7 sec to 27 sec.

Please could you advise what could be the reason of this slowness ? This slowness is mainly appearing on latest devices ( latest Android 11/12 ) and not on old devices ( Android 8/9/10 ). Please could you feedback and recommend how we should fix this issue ? Is there some specific settings to be done on these devices to accelerate the performance and make it stable? ( We have noticed that on latest devices there is an option related to power saving that can limit the CPU usage to 70% , we have disabled it but it didn’t helped. )

Please find related links :

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3899
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1306508#c10

Please find the performance from different devices provided by the client :

[performance time on android devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psbHo.png)

Thank you

Comment: I also have performance issues (really slowly) with android system web view 101 on some devices. In an Android 10 device i downgrade android system web view to version 74 and with that version the app works perfect.

Comment: @How to downgrade the Webview version